# Buffer in ArcMap with FLAT end lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, buffer

I have a polyline shapefile and I am applying a **Buffer tool in ArcMap 10.5 version** with `line_end_type='FLAT'`.

The **buffer** shape obtained **has not** all the end lines with a ***FLAT* end**, some of them are round ending [Picture].

I think that the problem is where are the start and end point of lines.
Is there a process to obtained all extreme ends of the lines with a flat end?

[image: Example of problem]

Comment: Yes, I specify `line_end_type='FLAT'` and some of the ends are round.

Comment: Edit your question and describe what format your data is in and coordinate system.

Comment: I have achieved it. First I applyed feature To Line tool and then I did the buffer with `line_end_type='FLAT'`

Comment: What were your features if they were not already lines?

Comment: The feature are Polyline. When I apply Feature to line tool I get a individual lines (Split the lines) and then I apply buffer tool.

Comment: So are you saying that they were originally multi-part, that may explain the behaviour of the tool?

Comment: For my case yes, but I cannot certificate it at 100%. My raw data were in dgn format files, which maybe had influence in buffer process.